# [VB.NET][2008] 2 forms show and close

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I create 2 Forms and show them in different method, "Show" and "ShowDialog".
I try to close the Form1 in the Form2 Load event, the DialogResult of the Form2 changed to "Cancel"? Is it a bug?

f1 is used for logo display and f2 is a login windows.
f1 show and stay 3 seconds. f2 show and wait for user login.

```
Private WithEvents f1 As Form
    Private WithEvents f2 As Form
    Private WithEvents bg As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

    Public Sub Run()
        Try
            bg = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
            f1 = New Form
            f1.Name = "Form1"
            f1.Show()
            Console.WriteLine("Show Form1 and stay 3 seconds")
            bg.RunWorkerAsync()

            f2 = New Form
            f2.Name = "Form2"
            Console.WriteLine("Show Form2 (ShowDialog)")
            Dim rlt = f2.ShowDialog()
            If rlt = DialogResult.Cancel Then
                Console.ReadKey()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub bg_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bg.DoWork
        Dim stw = Stopwatch.StartNew
        Do
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop Until stw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 3000
    End Sub

    Private Sub bg_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bg.RunWorkerCompleted
        Console.WriteLine("Form2's DialogResult = {0}", f2.DialogResult)
        f1.Close()
        Console.WriteLine("After Form1 close, Form2's DialogResult changed to ({0}). WHY?", f2.DialogResult)
    End Sub
```

#VB.NET

Comment: I can confirm the stated behaviour but I'm not sure why it happens. I can make an educated guess but that's about all. I'm not sure whether it's specifically by design or just the result of certain other behaviour that is by design. I will say that what you're doing - closing the modeless dialogue from the modal dialogue - is weird and pointless. Maybe you could explain what you're actually trying to achieve. The user can't access the modeless dialogue while the modal dialogue is open so it seems like closing `f1` before `f2` opens or after it closes would be the sensible option.

Comment: You don't need to persist with VB2008. You can download latest VS community edition for free: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/

Comment: f1 is used for logo display and f2 is a login windows.